Ruby GUI real time refresh entry with glimmer-libui
im making a GUI in ruby with the glimer dsl for libui and im using the multiline entry as read only as LOG. Where i open a txt file to read ir and then show it on the GUI multiline but it shows the results line per line just after around 10 seconds just for 900 lines in the text, meanwhile the GUI freezes, after that all lines appear in the multi entry. If i run just the .rb in command line, the lines prints line by line in real time like i want to show it in the GUI.
i already tried almost all forms to read the file and pass to the GUI but any makes the result i want.
Heres my code i tried to stream line per line and read the file
def open_tracks
    #tracks = File.open("tracks.txt")
    #array_tracks = IO.readlines('tracks.txt')
    #IO.foreach("tracks.txt") { |line| p line }
    #File.foreach(tracks).with_index do |line, line_num|
      #print "#{line_num}: #{line}"
    #end  
    file = File.new "tracks.txt"

    contents = file.read
    file.close
    return contents
end 

and the code i tried in the GUI side using the "on_clicked" button is this
           on_clicked do
            
            #tracks = open_tracks
            #count_tracks = tracks.readlines.size
            #mod_count = 100%count_tracks
            #count = 100/count_tracks
            
            #File.foreach(tracks).with_index do |line, line_num|
              #n = line_num + 1
              #@log.text = @log.text  << "#{n}: #{line}"
              #@bar.value += count
              #puts @bar.value
            #end
            #if (@bar.value<100)
              #@bar.value += mod_count
            #end
            
            #@log_label.text = "¡Cargados: #{count_tracks} tracks!"
            
            x = 0
            while x < open_tracks.length do
              @log.text = @log.text << open_tracks[x]
              x += 1
            end
          end

So i want to stream in "real time" line per line to the multi entry widget, and with that i can also chaging value of the progress bar until 100% (all lines printed)
